# Показ одной части из картинки

Tags: html, изображения, css

Как реализовать, чтобы из картинки с иконками показывало лишь одну из них.
Спасибо зарание.

Comment: И как подкласс сделать в css :DD

Comment: [**Читайте здесь.**][1]


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position

Answer (score 2):

Кусочек из темы jqueryui:

```
.ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
.ui-icon-triangle-1-se { background-position: -48px -16px; }
```

т.е. иконки по 16x16 пикселей, фон сдвигается на расстояние кратное 16 пикселям, для каждой иконки свой сдвиг.

про "подкласс" не понял. пример приведите.

Comment: Допустим есть класс .main как сделать чтобы было якобы .main и еще добавить в него что-то и как вводится это в html <div class="main" id="mainbg"> ?

Comment: ну как бы надо учить html в принципе если написать <div class="main subclass">текст</div> то браузер обработает 2 класса main и subclass и добавит стили из каждого!!! что касается картинки то все уже вывели

Comment: Спасбо помогли